# amcharts3 and ammap3 Parenthesized pattern error

Tags: angular, amcharts

I used npm install two modules in my webpack project:
1, npm install amcharts/amcharts3
2, npm install amcharts/ammap3

but got below error when i run 'npm start', does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

> ERROR in ./~/amcharts3/amcharts/serial.js
>   Module parse failed: /Users/xx/Documents/xx/node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/serial.js Parenthesized pattern (54:249)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts
>
> ERROR in ./~/ammap3/ammap/ammap.js
>   Module parse failed: /Users/xx/node_modules/ammap3/ammap/ammap.js Parenthesized pattern (173:426)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: They seem to have released a hotfix in `acorn`. If you upgrade to `4.0.8` it will be [fixed](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn/releases/tag/4.0.8).

```
npm install --save acorn@4.0.8
```

**EDIT**: It seems to be an issue with Webpack's dependency `acorn`. The `acorn` version `4.0.7` seems to break quite a lot of packages ([related](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4378)). A temporary workaround would be to lock the `acorn` dependency to a lower version:

```
// If webpack is a devDependency
$ npm install --save-dev acorn@4.0.4

// If webpack is a production dependency
$ npm install --save acorn@4.0.4
```

If you're using an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, you might want to change it to something like this:

```
"acorn": {
  "version": "4.0.4",
  "from": "acorn@>=4.0.4 <5.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-4.0.4.tgz"
},
```